# Importing fonts to scss module

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have downloaded a google font. I am importing the font in a `fonts.scss` file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poller One";
  src: local("Poller One"), url(./Fonts/PollerOne.ttf) format("ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RaleWay";
  src: local("RaleWay"), url(./Fonts/Raleway.ttf) format("ttf");
}
```

I am trying to use these fonts in another .scss file

home.module.scss

```
@import "../../fonts.scss";

h1 {
font-family: Poller One;
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It must be `format("truetype")`. Besides Font-family names containing whitespace must be wrapped in quotes. Check your dev tools network tab if you still don't see your font applied to HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misspelled font-family name:

```
@import "../../fonts.scss";

h1 {
  font-family: "Poller One"; /* Correct font family name within "" */
}
```

It should be working fine now.